# Android HERE SDK Voice in NavigationManager not work correctly

Tags: android, sdk, maps, voice, here-api

I use HERE Android SDK Turn-by-Turn Navigation. I have gotten download several languages (English, Spanish, French, German, etc..) They are saved in android/data/com.XX.XXX/files/voices-download folder.

Then, I setup the language to my navigationManager with the sentence:

navigationManager.setVoiceSkin(ConfigurationActivity.voiceCatalog.getLocalVoiceSkin(id));

but in modo Pedestrian I only hear the voice when the route ended. Why? I do not understand. can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Pedestrian navigation usually only provides beeps and vibrations for turns, and the final destination reached, so this is the expected behavior. Only car navigation provides spoken turn by turn instructions.